# Booting into Safe Mode just starts Automatic Repair Again

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, safe-mode

My PC suddenly stopped being able to boot a little while ago, which I attributed to some kind of graphics driver issue (after booting, the display was just black, though I could hear windows sounds). To address this, I booted into Automatic Repair (by turning on/off three times).

From the Automatic Repair screen, I choose Advanced options > Troubleshoot > Advanced Options > Startup Settings > Restart

This then displays a menu on boot where I can select lots of different boot modes. I choose Safe Mode with Networking.

Then, the machine restarts, only to show the Automatic Repair menu once again, and I'm back to where I started. So I cannot seem to enter safe mode at all. Any suggestions?

Edit: I also did enable the legacy safe mode key, F8. This gets me to the boot menu described above more quickly, but the same thing still ultimately happens.

Comment: If you installed Windows while in UEFI mode Legacy Mode must be disabled.  Enabling it absolutely will not help or solve your problem.

Comment: @Ramhound What I did was `bcdedit /set {default} bootmenupolicy legacy`

Comment: Yeah; If your using GPT that absolutely is not recommend and will not result in a working Windows installation.  You should not modify your boot configuration data like that.

Comment: @Ramhound suggesting that turning this back off might help things?

Answer (score 1):

The only way out I have ever seen from this is to pick the Reset Option.

See if you can boot from a bootable USB Key, and then get the data from your computer. Then try the Reset Option.

You should retain your data but I suggest backing it up beforehand.

It can be the case that the drive is badly corrupted and possibly damaged but do try backing it up.

Comment: There is a good chance that even Reset won’t work if the actual problem is caused by a failed storage device.  I have never seen massive boot failures in a system that wasn’t cause by the system drive failing.

Comment: I have seen it both ways and that I why I suggest backing up first.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do this next. I'm backing up everything via CMD right now. Everything is going smoothly so it seems not to be failed storage

Comment: Once backed up, try the Reset Process

Comment: @John It immediately fails due to an unknown problem

Comment: You think (from the above) the drive is OK (it still may have issues). Try a fresh install and if that fails, the drive may have some damage.

Comment: @John via a USB, or you just mean to not select the "keep my files" option?

Comment: Try the the repair / install ISO on USB and then try keeping files. That might work.

Comment: Did the Repair Install work for you?